# Can 2 different Java programs running in 2 different Eclipse Workspaces, read each other?

Tags: eclipse, server, jetty

I have one common app (Let's call CommmonApp) which needs to be up continuously for other specific (Let say one of them is - SpecificApp) app's' to run.

I need to switch between different git repositories during development and have to perform series of steps such as Clean Build and Maven Update to have the workspace in runnable/clean state and then also every time I have to start CommonApp in all those repository workspaces.

If I run CommonApp from some other repository in Eclipse 1 and run SpecificApp from another repository in Eclipse 2, SpecifcApp is not able to read CommonApp.
The medium of communication between these apps is REST APIs, so I assumed that it will work but it is not.

Is it possible or too wishful? Hope I haven't confused.

Comment: Eclipse does not give any help here.  You need to use standard tools for communicating between JVM's.

Comment: Pretty vague description of the issue.  What happens? Logs? What have you tried?  What have you done to diagnose it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What kind of tools would you suggest?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I have run with given setup and the apps dont identify REST APIs running on 2 different eclipse instances.

Comment: Make _two_ different clones each with their own branch.   I